# Windows 8 application UI Thread falls into deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a windows 8 application.

So my primary thread is a UI thread. From my page classes i call my Method A which in turn calls Method B which in turn calls Library Method LibA which again calls Method LibB which in turns call an async method (AsynLibCAsync) and awaits on it.

Library async method is actually httpclient.sendAsync of HTTPClient class

Its like this

```
OnNavigatedTo( Page class UI Thread ) -> A ->B-> LibA ->LibB - > httpclient.sendAsync
```

None of the methods in the chain are async so it goes into the deadlock as nicely explained here

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

So what i did was i made methods (OnNavigatedTO ,A,B) async.  And i waited for B in A.
As per the blog the high level method must be made into Async such that the UI context does not get hang.

So its like this now

```
Async OnNavigatedTo -> AAsync -> BAsync -> LiB A -> LibB -> httpclient.sendAsync
```

But still the call runs into deadlock. 
Any help will be hugely appreciated.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: You need turtles all the way down.  Or use ConfigureAwait(false), the obvious solution.

Comment: thanks Hans...I changed the library method by using ConfigureAwait(false) and it worked. But in the production i cannot change the library method.

Comment: If the library itself is not async, why is it using the `HttpClient.SendAsync()` method? In any case, it really would be best to convince whomever needs to be convinced to let the library implement the API as an async API. You can "solve" the problem as suggested by the one answer (wrap the call in `Task.Run()`), but this fails to take full advantage of the underlying asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LibA()` must also be async in order that the method is called async...

Try instead of directly calling `LibA()` try `await Task.Run(() => { LibA(); });` in `BAsync`...

Comment: thanks a ton... it worked...but best would be to make the changes in the library method call i guess

Comment: yes, its not a nice solution... the library should be designed with async through the call stack..